# Ruta personalizada para los archivos javascript - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routing

Tengo varios archivos javascripts que estan  en la carpeta `/content/` y hago las referencias a esos archivos en la vista `/Views/Home/Index.cshml`:

```
<script src="~/content/js/main.js" />
<script src="~/content/js/header.js" />
```

Ahora bien, necesito personalizar la urls de esos archivos a:

```
<script src="~/content/js/VERSION_2_1_4_23/main.js" />
<script src="~/content/js/VERSION_2_1_4_23/header.js" />
```

Donde `VERSION_2_1_4_23` es una ruta que no existe y que puede cambiar, pero aun si debería de siempre cargar el archivo que esta `~/content/js/main.js`.

Como puedo lograr esto?

***Actualizacion 1:***
El motivo por el que necesito esto es para forzar al navegador a que cargue el archivo otra vez e ignore el que tiene en cache. Se que existen varias opciones como por ejemplo agregar un parametro dinamico al final de la url del archivo como por ejemplo:

```
<script src="~/content/js/main.js?version=2_1_4_23" />
```

Pero esto no me funciona, el navegador me sigue cargando el archivo anterior en cache. Y las combinaciones `CTRL + SHIFT + R` no es una opcion ya que los usuarios que utilizan la aplicación se pueden confundir con facilidad.

***Actualizacion 2:*** Aquí la imagen del archivo que sigue cargando del cache:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A pesar que puedo forzar el parametro `v={ramdon_string}` a cambiar, igual lo sigue cargando del cache.

---

Nota:
Es algo parecido a los routing de ASP.NET MVC donde se puede especificar una ruta dinamica a una vista de un controlador. Por ejemplo:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "dashboard",
                url: "dasboard/{content_id}/view",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dasboard", content_id = @"\d+", action = "view" });
}
```

En esa url, `{content_id}` es un numero dinámico e igual carga la vista que esta en la carpeta `~/Views/Dashboard/View.cshtml`.

Comment: ¿Y si creas una carpeta con ese nombre? ¿O necesitas crear virtualmente esa ubicación por algún motivo no mencionado en la pregunta?

Comment: @fredyfx actualize la respuesta agregando el motivo. Dale una mirada.

Comment: Me parece extraño, ¿has intentado usar puntos en lugar de guiones abajo?

Comment: @fredyfx Si. Lo intente sin puntos, con puntos y dash e iguial sigue cargando el archivo en cache. Se que es el mismo archivo porque me sigue mostrando un mensaje que no esta en el archivo js actual.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el detalle está en la forma de cómo entregas esos archivos, intenta lo siguiente:

```
private static void AddAppBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
   {
       var path = "admin";
       var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/js/app");
       var FullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/{0}", path));
       if (Directory.Exists(FullPath))
       {
           scriptBundle.Include(
               // Order matters
               string.Format("~/{0}/app.module.js", path),
               string.Format("~/{0}/app.core.module.js", path)
               )

               .IncludeDirectory(string.Format("~/{0}", path), "*.module.js", true)
               .IncludeDirectory(string.Format("~/{0}", path), "*.js", true);
       }
       bundles.Add(scriptBundle);
   }
```

En el `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/js/app")
```

Y te generará:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/layout/layout.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/blocks/apiendpoint.config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/blocks/apiendpoint.provider.js"></script>
```

Ahora bien, lo que queremos es añadir una variable para evitar que se quede en cache.

```
@{  
    string version = typeof(yourProjectNamespace.WebApiApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
}
    <!--app scripts.-->
    @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}?nocache="+ version +"\"></script>", "~/js/app")
```

Y esto genera:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js?nocache=1.28.16145.10"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/config.js?nocache=1.28.16145.10"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.js?nocache=1.28.16145.10"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/layout/layout.module.js?nocache=1.28.16145.10"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/blocks/apiendpoint.config.js?nocache=1.28.16145.10"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/blocks/apiendpoint.provider.js?nocache=1.28.16145.10"></script>
```

Respuesta extraída y traducida de: http://www.jomendez.com/2016/05/26/how-to-avoid-js-files-cache-script-bundle-with-razor/

Comment: Lo intente y aunque si cargo algunos archivos, no los cargo todos. Tuve que hacer limpiar el cache manualmente para poder ver los cambios. Intente incluso asignado la propiedad `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` e igual algunos archivos no cargaron

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir capturas de pantalla de inspección de elementos de la pestaña de network por favor?

Comment: Actualize la pregunta. Dale una mirada.

Comment: ¿Ahora le has dado control F5?

Comment: Como te mencione, no es una opcion hacer combinaciones de teclas. El publico que utiliza la aplicacion se puede confundir facilmente y son muchos los usuarios que utilizan la aplicación. Por lo que es NECESARIO que se limpie el cache sin intervención del usuario.

Comment: Entiendo, buena suerte bro, ya no tengo más ideas.